# Could not get EGL Display - Starting RetroPie

Tags: display, retropie, sdl

I have manually installed RetroPie, using the terminal and some tutorials..
Finally ready to start everything up... and then get this error:

Error Creating SDL window!
Could not get EGL display
Renderer failed to initialize!
Window failed to initialize!

Then I changed the dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d code. Taking it off (and later also back on again in the config.txt.) Also Tried changing GL drivers.

Now the error is: * failed to add service - already in use?

What to do now?

Answer (score 2):

Set the Pi to boot to command line only.

This can be done by selecting the option from the gui menu somehow (no gui handy at the mo) or via

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Select option 3 then B1 then B1 or B2 (I recommend to use a password).

Do not run the desktop.

Start retro-pi from the command line.

By the way, retro-pi have a very good set of support users at [their own forum](https://retropie.org.uk/forum/)