# Retro pi not booting up said error creating SLD window

Tags: retropie

Error creating SLD window!
Could not initalize EGL

Comment: [exact  duplicate](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112219/could-not-get-egl-display-starting-retropie)